# How do I get Mail to show desktop alerts when I get mail?

Tags: macos, email, osx-snow-leopard, notifications, apple-mail

How do I get Mail to show desktop alerts or start bouncing around when I get mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Gmail you might just want to use [Google Notifier for Mac](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html).
It also notifies you about upcoming Google Calendar events. 
Also check similar superuser [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/115757/google-notifier-replacement-for-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 3):

Install [Growl](http://growl.info/) and [Growlmail](http://growl.info/growlmail/) (or some other Growl [mail addon](http://growl.info/applications.php?cat=Email) for different mail programs or online mail).

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin: [Herald](http://erikhinterbichler.com/software/herald/)
It's free and vorks good. can be customized. 5 stars!